# Azure Function Singleton Service thread Safe?

Tags: azure-functions, thread-safety, singleton

I'm working with Azure-functions, and I have a class that has been configured as singleton inside the DI configuration, the class exposes 2 methods:

```
public void methodA(out objectA)
{
  ...
  methodB(out objectA.objectB)
  objectA.xxx = ....
  ...
}

public void methodB(out objectB)
{
  ...
  objectB = ...
}
```

After reading about singleton, my understanding is that it will be like a global variable. Because of that I suspect that there is a possibility that one instance of an AF could call methodA and another instance of AF could call methodB and override the value objectA.objectB that was set on the first function...

I tried to prove this with an unit test.

```
public void Multithread_Test()
{
    ...
    singletonClass.methodA(out objectA);
    ...
    singletonClass.methodB(out objectB);
    ...
    Assert.AreEqual(objectB, objectA.objectB);
}
```

This didn't work, and I see at least 2 problems on the test:

1. First, the call to methodA finished before the call to methodB started, here they are synchronously called(I don't have multiple AF instances).
2. Second, the DI container is not really working here, so by using the same instance of singletonClass I may be not doing the same think that the DI container does...

UPDATE:

Now I'm trying something like:

```
        public void Multithread_Test()
        {
            ...
            Parallel.Invoke(
                () =>
                    {
                        singletonClass.methodA(out objectA);
                        Assert.AreEqual(objectA.objectB, expectedObjectB);
                        //expectedObjectB != expectedObjectC
                    },
                () => {
                        singletonClass.methodB(out objectC)
                        Assert.AreEqual(objectC, expectedObjectC);
                        //expectedObjectB != expectedObjectC
                      }
                );

        }
```

I'm also adding a ThreadSleep just after the function call to methodB, but the result seems to point to everything working ok, no override...

My question/s are:

- Is the code thread-safe? or my fears are correct?
- What is the best way to test this, when using AF, DI?

Comment: does you singleton have any state?

Comment: @Mike I think it does not. It has 2 methods which received an out parameter, do some calculations and populate this out parameter, one of the methods also calls the other one. Apart from that there is no member variables(except a Log object) and no references to external variables/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton with no state will not have any thread safety issues